# Backup Outlook Emails and be able to access them without Username and Password?

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook

A coworker of mine is leaving my company tomorrow and wants to pass all of his Emails over to me when he leaves. The problem is, when we back these emails up, they require his Username and Password to access them. I already have this password, but I'm afraid that his account will be disabled when he leaves; Leaving me with a bunch of emails that can't be opened.

Is there a way that I can back these emails up, as there are a lot of reference drawings and company documents that I will need once he is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach might be to archive them to a separate "pst" file stored somewhere on your network.

You should then be able to read that in Outlook without needing your colleague's username and password.

I don't have Outlook installed on this machine to double check the procedure, but the option should be in the file menu. Select the folders you want to export and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a PST if you are using Outlook.
2. If you still don't want to use PST, then open Outlook, select the email(s) you want to make a copy, Press Ctrl+C and then go to the directory you want to Paste the item. and Paste Ctrl+V. This will create a backup.

The Second doesn't require a password to view the mail. Where as for the first you need to enter password, if you have set.